# Deserialize empty json propertyname

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json object coming from a web api which looks something like this:

```
{"":[{"id":1, "name":"name1"}, {"id":2, "name":"name2"}]}
```

and I have corresponding C# class for deserialize:

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

but whenever I deserialize using Json.NET the `Persons` property in `RootObject` class is
always null.

```
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

I know the problem is very trivial, I really appreciate if anyone can help me out to fix this up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Json string is flawed, if you change

`{"":[{"id":1, "name":"name1"}, {"id":2, "name":"name2"}]}`

to

`{"Persons":[{"id":1, "name":"name1"}, {"id":2, "name":"name2"}]}`

it deserializes just fine.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing it right now (locally)! Unfortunately, I don't really have control over server side code.

Comment: Not sure if it helps or works but try adding [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "")] to the Persons property in the RootObject class